# Split Container Indicator flickers when on moving it

Tags: winforms, splitcontainer

We have a split container added in our WinForm application. The problem is that when I move the splitter indicator from left to right or vice-versa to resize the two panels, it starts to flicker.

Below are the few observations related to flickering:

- When the application is launched in Windows Server 2008: No flickering is observed
- When the same application is launched from Windows Server 2012/2016 - The flickering starts.

Note: The two panel don't flicker. It's only the indicator that flickers.

Comment: Did you set the form's `DoubleBuffered` property to true?

Comment: [How to: Reduce Graphics Flicker with Double Buffering for Forms and Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Currently, we are not setting it to any value. Is it expected to be true to reduce flickering?

Comment: No, it comes set to false by default. Try setting it to true and see if you get better results.

Comment: private void splitContainer1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         //do your code
        }

Comment: I tried with DoubleBuffered set to true. The split indicator stays at one position until I finish resizing and then it paints all at once. However, it doesn't solve the purpose because the other shadow split indicator which we see when we resize the actual indicator, still flickers. I want to resolve that flickering. Is there any other way? Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: I tried with DoubleBuffered once and the OptimizedDoubleBuffered as well, but I continue to see this issue. Its only the splitter that flickers. Neither the two panels nor the controls within these two panels, flicker